# Single page links are not working in wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am getting something weird issue with my website. I have add some links to my website home page to another page. Something like this

```
www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/#pro1
www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/#pro2
www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/#pro3
www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/#pro4
```

Now when I click on any link it will send me to `div pro1` on any of the link I click.. Please check the html also for that page

```
<!--  section  1  image-->
<div id="pro2" name="pro2">
    <div class="inner-image-width">
        <div class="inner-left">
            <div class="titleinner">Unlimited possibilities   </div>
            Some text
        </div>
    <div class="inner-right">
        <img width="500" height="325" src="http://fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/product1.jpg"  alt="product image1">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!--  section  1  no image-->
<div id="pro1" name="pro1">
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div ><div class="titleinner">Boost in revenue </div>
```

Some text

```
<!--  section  2  image-->
<div id="p5">
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div class="inner-left">
<div class="titleinner">Improved customer experience  </div>
Some text</div>
<div class="inner-right"><img width="500" height="325" src="http://fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/product4.jpg"  alt="product image1"></div>
</div>
</div>

<!--  section  2  no image-->
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div>
<div class="titleinner">Confidence in security  </div>
Some text</div>
</div>

<!--  section  3 image-->
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div class="inner-left">
<img width="500" height="325" src="http://fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/product3.jpg"  alt="product image1">
</div>
<div class="inner-right"><div class="titleinner">Happier staff   </div>
Some text</div>
</div>

<!--  section  3 no image-->
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div><div class="titleinner">Optimized marketing campaigns  </div>
Some text 
</div>
</div>

<!--  section 4  image-->
<div id="pro3" name="pro3" onlclick="window.location.hash = '#pro3'";>
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div class="inner-left">
<div class="titleinner">Secure payments  </div>
Some text</div>
<div class="inner-right"><img width="500" height="325" src="http://fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/product6.jpg"  alt="product image1"></div>
</div>
</div>

<!--  section  4  no image-->
<div id="pro4" name="pro4">
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div><div class="titleinner">Fun entertainment   </div>
Some text</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--  section  5  image-->
<div id="pro6" name="pro6">
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div class="inner-left">
<img width="500" height="325" src="http://fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/product5.jpg"  alt="product image1">
</div>
<div class="inner-right"><div class="titleinner">Reduced operating costs    </div>
Some text</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--  section  5  no image-->
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div>
<div class="titleinner">Immediate improvements </div>
Some text</div>

</div>

<!--  section 6  image-->
<div class="inner-image-width">
<div class="inner-left">
<div class="titleinner">Increased brand loyalty   </div>
Some text</div>
<div class="inner-right"><img width="500" height="325" src="http://fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/product2.jpg"  alt="product image1"></div>
</div>


<!--  section  6 no image-->
<div class="inner-image-width">

<div><div class="titleinner">Minimal risk  </div>
Some text</div>
</div>

<div style="font-size:24px;"><a href="http://fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/contact/" target="_blank">Contact us</a> Some text</div>
```

I try every solution of stackoverflow but nothing work. Can anybody please help me this

Comment: hash links are used for same page navigation. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: hash link should be open in new page and should be focus on particular div @MohitBhardwaj

Comment: can you share your website link here also possible page links example ?

Comment: if your website link http://fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/contact/ then no need to put whole link jus add this one <a href="/contact/">contact us</a> same for /#pro1/ whatever you going to use . otherwise, reset your permalink to default , and then save it again go to the permalink and set as %postname %

Comment: You need to add link for that page and then append `#pro1` to it. Currently, I think you are only adding the `#pro1` part, which will cause it to lookup on current page. Website link would be helpful.

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj http://jukeslotselfservice.com/ links you can find below sliders there are six boxes that will open new page

Comment: @azad and after clicking the link where would you like to target it , send me the link , I am bitt confused would send me the link where would you want to target these links?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj the link should be same but it is not going to the particular div

Comment: The links are working fine as you targeted it if you click pro6 link it will show the section where you put the div id Reduced operating costs . so if you want show saprate section for each link then you need to create all these section with a saprate page and then change links with uniqe page name .Currently you have create it all in one page

Comment: Yes I did some changes and now its working I have apply div id to inner div of parent div and its start working @RajKumarBhardwaj

Answer (score 0):

You just use this:

```
<a href="#pro1">Pro 1</a>
```

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using bookmarks(#hushtag) in your URL.

Check out [HTML Links - Create a Bookmark](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

> HTML bookmarks are used to allow readers to jump to specific parts of
>   a Web page.
>
> Bookmarks are practical if your website has long pages.
>
> To make a bookmark, you must first create the bookmark, and then add a
>   link to it.
>
> When the link is clicked, the page will scroll to the location with
>   the bookmark.

In your case,

```
www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/#pro1 -> click this link will jump to div #pro1

www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/#pro2 -> click this link will jump to div #pro2

www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/#pro3 -> click this link will jump to div #pro3

www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/#pro4 -> click this link will jump to div #pro4
```

Basically, your URL bookmarks(#hushtag) works fine.

If you want to link to another page, just avoid using hashtag, maybe like this:

www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/pro1.php -> click this will link to 'pro1.php'

like this:

```
<a href="http://www.fsfsdafsdafdsafsadf/pro1.php">link text</a>
<a href="pro1.php">link text</a>
```